# Twilio and Nuance ASR possibility

Tags: twilio, speech-recognition, naturallyspeaking

Does anyone have experience using twilio and Nuance ASR (https://developer.nuance.com/public/index.php?task=memberServices) for creating voice recognizing applications?\

I'm thinking the time lag would not make it feasible. For example, if I we were to prompt the user to say something and get Nuance to recognize it and give me back the transcription and then I look that up in my system for further actions would simply take too long.

1. Capture audio from user,
2. take voice recording url from twilio,
3. and pass on the audio file to nuance
4. Then take transcription from nuance
5. match the words against my data
6. take appropriate action

This all should happen fairly quick, but is it quick enough to be acceptable for a caller?

any thoughts would be great
Thank you

ps. I tried to create the tag Nuance, but was not allowed

Answer (score 2):

I am currently working on communication platform which offers real-time translation and I'm using Twilio as platform provider for our autom. translated voice call feature. The ASR tech from Nuance is average to say the least and is absolutely not usable with low band audio. Check out the Google Cloud Speech API. I achieved very good results with it. ASR takes around 3-5 seconds.

Comment: Thank you,
What do you do in the 3-5 seconds it takes to get results processed? do you play some kind of hold tone or music?

Answer (score 1):

Nuance Recognizer does work with low-band audio - in fact it is designed to be used in a telephony environment - the comment previously is incorrect. However, the problem is getting an audio stream from Twilio back to Recognizer in a timely fashion for partial recognition. Typically Nuance Recognizer integrates with IVR platforms using MRCP but I don't think Twilio supports this protocol. So, if using a third party engine, you may have to record the phrase, then submit (transfer it) to your ASR instance, process the response, and send back the results to Twilio - this induces latency since the ASR engine cannot process partial audio. Simple example of the problem - if someone is talking for 10 seconds, the results won't come back to Twilio for 10 seconds (recording time) + transfer time + processing time + return time to Twilio.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question but this question still comes up on the 1st page of google search results for `twilio asr`.

It is a shameless plug-in but our company Voicegain has developed a recognizer that works very much like Nunance ASR (takes GRXML grammars for example) and also provided Twilio Media Streams integration enabling easy use as an ASR for Twilio. The advantage compared to say using Google STT with Twilio is that our recognizer natively uses grammars so accuracy may be much higher than Google STT on specific use cases, plus our recognizer supports complete-timeout, i.e., it is aware that the grammar matched and will switch to the shorter complete-timeout from the longer incomplete-timeout.

See here: [www.voicegain.ai/post/announcing-twilio-twiml-connect-stream-support](https://www.voicegain.ai/post/announcing-twilio-twiml-connect-stream-support)